# libcups2:i386 package can be installed on Ubuntu 20.04 but not in Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, printing, dependencies, repository, 32-bit

In **Xubuntu** 20.04 amd64 I can´t install the libcups2:i386, package dependencies errors:

```
libavahi-client3:i386
libavahi-common3:i386 (>= 0.6.16)
libc6:i386 (>= 2.28)
libgnutls30:i386 (>= 3.6.12)
libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (>= 1.17)
zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.0)
```

[image: xubuntu synaptic config]
[image: ubuntu synaptic config]

**Ubuntu installation** cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

**Xubuntu live usb** cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb cdrom:[Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)]/ focal main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

**Xubuntu installation** cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)]/ focal main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

**Ubuntu**: Results of `apt policy libcups2:i386` :

```
libcups2:i386:
  Installed: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.3.1-9ubuntu1 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

**Xubuntu**: Results of `apt policy libcups2:i386` :

```
libcups2:i386:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1
  Tabla de versión:
     2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
     2.3.1-9ubuntu1 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

**Xubuntu**: Results of `sudo apt install libcups2:i386` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an 
impossible  situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libcups2:i386 : 
    Depends: libavahi-client3:i386 (>= 0.6.16) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libavahi-common3:i386 (>= 0.6.16) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libgnutls30:i386 (>= 3.6.12) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (>= 1.17) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

dpkg --print-architecture

```
amd64
```

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

```
i386
```

Comment: It is in place https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libcups2 . Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: hi! @Organic Marble , thanks for your help

I just checked the configuration of my ubuntu 20.04 and xubuntu 20.04 and in xubuntu I don't know why the focal-updates repository is disabled even with the same repository configuration in synaptic

is this normal on xubuntu default install¿? https://i.imgur.com/W4e4Neg.png

Comment: I don't know why the updates repo would be commented out. On 20.04, I only have an Ubuntu MATE system, and it is not commented out there. The package `ibcups2:i386` is also in the `focal-security` repo, not just updates, so I would guess that your sources list is really messed up.  Why would you not want updates or security repos enabled? Can't imagine.

Comment: Also, it really annoys people here when you post images of terminal text in a question. I suggest you edit your question to include the text, not image links to click on.

Comment: it's weird, it's a clean installation by default, actually the one that is commented on is the source code repository, the binaries are not listed

Comment: @OrganicMarble . I just edited my post with the content of my sources.list

Comment: I'm confused, are the repos commented out or not? It does not look like it, only the source code repos. Consider doing a `apt policy libcups2:i386` and adding the text output to your question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble done!

Comment: OK, so your question is a bit off. The package *is* in the repositories. You just can't install it.  Suggest totally editing your question including the title to focus on the real problem. Get rid of all the stuff about the repos.

Comment: Long shot, but is your system a 64 bit system and you haven't enabled 32 bit architecture? You can see by doing a `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, if you don't get an answer of `i386`, it's not enabled.

Comment: Hi! This is the result:

dpkg --print-architecture -> amd64
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures -> i386

so, i understand that multi-arch support is enabled

thanks!